# modular arithmetic congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Simplify the following congruence:
$$−169 \equiv \text{ ?}  \mod 52 $$
(By simplify, we mean find the smallest non-negative whole number which is congruent to $-169$ modulo $52$.)

Simplify the following congruence:

$$−501 \equiv \text { ?}  \mod 213$$ 
(By simplify, we mean find the smallest non-negative whole number which is congruent to $-501$ modulo $213$.)

Comment: Keep adding 52 until you get a small positive number....

Answer (score 2):

If we use division with remainder, we obtain

$$169 = 3 \cdot 52 + 13$$

Multiplying each side of the equation by $-1$ yields

$$-169 = -3 \cdot 52 - 13$$

Hence, $-169 \equiv -13 \pmod{52}$.  However, $-13 < 0$, so we add and subtract $52$ to the right side of the equation.

\begin{align*}
-169 & = -3 \cdot 52 - 13\\
     & = -3 \cdot 52 - 52 + 52 - 13\\
     & = -4 \cdot 52 + 39
\end{align*}

Thus, $-169 \equiv 39 \pmod{52}$.  Since $0 \leq 39 < 52$, $39$ is the smallest non-negative integer congruent to $-169 \pmod{52}$.

You can apply the same strategy in your second problem.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest, non-negative number which is congruent to $-169$ modulo $52$ is called the *least residue* of $-169$ modulo $52$.

Note that $-169 + ( 4 \times 52 ) = 39$, so $-169 \equiv 39 \mod 52$.

Try this yourself for the second question.

Comment: how did you get the four?

Comment: @Nicole Four is the number of times you need to add 52 to -169 to get a positive number.  Note that adding any lesser multiple of 52 will leave you with a negative number.